Можно ли использовать SLAAC автоконфигурацию IPv6 на тунельных интерфейсах маршрутизаторов Cisco?
Делаю лабу в универе. Тестирую такую простую топологию:

На интерфейсе f0 роутера R5 назначен ipv4 адрес 1.1.1.1 
На интерфейсе f0 роутера R6 назначен ipv4 адрес 1.1.1.2 
Также на роутерах созданы туннельные интерфейсы типа ipv6ip 
Тестирую пинги, всё работает прекрасно. 
Пытаюсь на интерфейсе tunnel 0 у R5 включить автоконфигурацию командой ipv6 address autoconfig default, но ни к какому результату это не приводит, маршрут по умолчанию не появляется.
Тестировал в GNS версии 0.8.7 и 2.2.46. Использую маршрутизатор Сisco 1700. 
Полную конфигурацию, если кому то нужна, прилагаю.
R5
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
interface Tunnel0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FD00::1/64
 ipv6 address autoconfig default
 ipv6 enable
 tunnel source 1.1.1.1
 tunnel destination 1.1.1.2
 tunnel mode ipv6ip
!
interface FastEthernet0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 speed auto

R6
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
interface Tunnel0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FD00::2/64
 ipv6 enable
 tunnel source 1.1.1.2
 tunnel destination 1.1.1.1
 tunnel mode ipv6ip
!
interface FastEthernet0
 ip address 1.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
 speed auto
!

Где то видел информацию о том, что не все типы туннелей поддерживают автоконфигурирование IPv6, но понять какой именно тип используется в Cisco IOS не смог :(

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Единственное, что помогло, - это использовать более новую версию маршрутизатора (Cisco 7200) и новую версию GNS.
